# Is there a single place where I can put content on an ASP.NET MVC 4 website that will show up on every page?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, http-headers, clickjacking

I have an MVC 4 site and I want to prevent users from showing my site in an iframe.  I know I must add the XFO header `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` with the value `DENY` in my responses but I wanted to ask if there is a single place where I can put this so that all my responses send this.

Comment: http://tjrus.com/blog/block_the_loading_of_your_site_through_iframe_for_third_party_sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who needs to do this in the future, this is how I did this

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Headers["X-FRAME-OPTIONS"] = "DENY";
}
```